# Bold and Italic texts styles are too big

Tags: macros

I have a problem with my \textbf and \textit commands, it makes my texts bigger than when no styles are applied.

An example is shown here:

[image]

I also put an URL inside the bold command (`\textbf{http://www.stackoverflow.com/}`) and it doesn't go back to the new line, so i have to manually put a space between words...

This is basically my header:

```
% Packages 
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\fontsize{12}{12}
pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
        \subsubsection {Origin}
        \par
        Lorem ipsum \textbf{sit dolor amet}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show your setup.

Comment: I can't see any problems with your example code, except for a missing `\ ` before `pagenumbering`.

Comment: Your edited example is not sufficient to comment, please complete it to be a complete document that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example isn't usable however the default bold fonts in the default Computer Modern font setup are *bold extended* (`bx`). Computer Modern also has a bold unextended series (`b`) which may be selected as shown.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

abcdefghi

\textbf{abcdefghi}

{\fontseries{b}\selectfont abcdefghi}

\end{document}
```